# Create Dates Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create an array of dates in Javascript based on a start date and an end date.  I need the date format to look like `2013-04-25`

My code apparently doesn't work, but I can't seem to figure out why.  Can someone assist?

```
//get today's date
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());

//get date from last week -7
var prevWeek = new Date();
prevWeek.setDate(prevWeek.getDate() -7);

//set initial date parameters
  var fromDate = prevWeek;
  var toDate = today;

//set date parameters to input parameters
function setDates() {
    fromDate =document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
    toDate = document.getElementById('toDate').value;
};

var dates = new Array();

//create date array
function setArray() {
    for(i = fromDate.getDate(), i <= toDate.getDate(), i.setDate(i.getDate() +1))
    {
    dates.push(new Date(i));
    };
};

//format date array
function formDates() {
    for(i = 0, i <= dates.length, i++)
    {
        var dd = dates[i].getDate();
        var mm = dates[i].getMonth()+1;
        var yyyy = dates[i].getFullYear();
        if(dd<10)   {dd = '0' + dd};
        if(mm<10){mm = '0' + mm};
        dates[i] = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    };
};
```

Comment: you say it doesn't work. What are you experiencing. Nothing at all? or do you have errors?

Comment: Your `setArray()` is giving you troubles, I would rethink that loop also your loop signatures are wrong. they should be delimited with `;`. - http://www.jslint.org/ + if you could give us your HTML that would be great :)

Comment: @limelights, that was the problem! I was using `,` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop signatures are wrong.

They should be delimited with `;` and not a `,`

A correct javascript for loop is made like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
}
```

Using `var` statements here are also considered best practice due to javascript otherwise hoisting your `i` variable making it global to the function, or worst case scenario, your entire js-file.